# Array lookup not resizing

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have two worksheets `Sheet3` and `Sheet4`. `Sheet3` only has values in column A, `Sheet4` has values in columns A and B.

The code below creates a one-dimensional array for `Sheet3` and a one-dimensional array for `Sheet4`, then compares the two and outputs the correct value in `Sheet3` column B . Because the code was somewhat slow, so I decided to resize my arrays and now my code does not work anymore.

Any suggestion on how I can resize the arrays without the code to break?

Thanks for your help!

```
Sub ArrayCompare()

Dim Array1() As Variant, Array2() As Variant

ReDim Array1(1 To 1000)

    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
            Array1(i) = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

ReDim Preserve Array1(1 To i)

ReDim Array2(1 To 1000, 1 To 1000)

    For i = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
        For j = LBound(Array2, 2) To UBound(Array2, 2)
            Array2(i, j) = Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i

ReDim Preserve Array2(1 To i, 1 To j) 'Error occurs here

    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
        For j = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
            If Array1(i) = Array2(j, 1) Then

                Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value = Array2(j, 2)

            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can only reDim the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Find the dimensions of the data range first then redim the arrays

Comment: Ok, so change `ReDim Preserve Array2(1 To i, 1 To j)` to`ReDim Preserve Array2( 1 To j)` would be the fix for the first issue?

Comment: Have you considered doing `Array1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value)` (assuming you are wanting to get all the cells in column A), and `Array2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1", Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet4").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value` (assuming Array2 is meant to be a two-dimensional array containing columns A and B)

Comment: Note:  In your current code `i` and `j` will both have the value 1001 at the points where the `ReDim`s are occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

edited to add faster alternatives

You can avoid all that dimming and redimming

---

**"base"** solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayCompare()
    Dim Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant

    Array1 = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A1000")).Value
    Array2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:B1000").Value

    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
        For j = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
            If Array1(i) = Array2(j, 1) Then Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value = Array2(j, 2)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Boost #1**

to make it faster you could avoid writing many times to the worksheet, so:

- remove

  ```
  Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2).Value = Array2(j, 2)
  ```

  from the loop
- and place:

  ```
  Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B1000").Value = Array1
  ```

  right out of it

the code becomes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrayCompare1()
    Dim Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Array1 = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B1000").Value
    Array2 = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:B1000").Value

    For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
        For j = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
            If Array1(i, 1) = Array2(j, 1) Then Array1(i, 2) = Array2(j, 2)
        Next j
    Next i
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B1000").Value = Array1
End Sub
```

---

**Boost #2**

to make the above code even faster you could limit `Array1` and `Array2` to their actually *necessary* sizes instead of using a `large` enough size

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub ArrayCompare2()
        Dim Array1 As Variant, Array2 As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long

        Array1 = GetArray("Sheet3")
        Array2 = GetArray("Sheet4")

        For i = LBound(Array1) To UBound(Array1)
            For j = LBound(Array2) To UBound(Array2)
                If Array1(i, 1) = Array2(j, 1) Then Array1(i, 2) = Array2(j, 2)
            Next j
        Next i
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:B1").Resize(UBound(Array1)).Value = Array1
    End Sub

    Function GetArray(shtName As String)
        With Worksheets(shtName)
            GetArray = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
        End With
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @user3598756 this works perfectly! But it is just as quick as my code before I tried to resize the arrays. I know this was not part of my question, but is there anything I can do in terms of efficiency to speed up the lookup? I was under the impression that resizing would be the efficiency gains using an array.

Comment: Redimming is a slow horse. What's your real goal?

Comment: I run spreadsheets against each other to look up values using normal loops. Some of the spreadsheets contain over 100,000 rows of data so running some of the comparisons takes 10 minutes. I was told that if I use arrays instead it would be way faster, but when I run my normal loop against the code above, my regular loop is way quicker.

Comment: So my real goal is to find these fast array loops that I have told about :)

Comment: @VBAPete What do you want to resize the arrays **TO**?  At the moment, your original code is just trying to resize them to be `(1 To 1001)` and `(1 To 1001, 1 To 1001)` which is slightly larger than they started at, but there's nothing in the code showing that you are really trying to make them smaller.  If you are just trying to size them so they only contain non-empty cells, it is easier to do that as you read them in rather than after you have created them.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks, That's good to know. I was under the impression, that you first create a "too large" array and then resize it to make it fit.

Comment: @VBAPete - You **can**, but (as per the comment I made to the question itself, which is similar to user3598756's answer, except replacing `1000` with an `End(xlup)` type last row calculation) it is easier to just only read in the information you want and allow VBA to set the size - no need for loops to get the data in (which would be slow), no need to work out afterwards how big you want the array, etc.  (But my comment only works if you are trying to resize the array so that it has the same rows as non-empty cells in the data.  If you are doing something different, that won't work.)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for your explanation, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: VBAPete and @YowE3K, see edited answer where I added two different "boost" levels handling what YowE3k suggested about limiting array sizes  and adding to that the removal of worksheet writing from the loop

Comment: The OP's original code only stores values in **some** cells.  **IF** some of the non-updated cells contained formulas (and I stress that they might **not**), writing the whole range out again from the array will replace those formulas with values.  @VBAPete will need to check whether that will be an issue before implementing these "boosts".  (P.S. I love your naming of these enhancements as "boosts".)

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and the updated code guys. This is so helpful! I think I am finally get the hang of arrays.

Comment: @user3598756 Btw, your boosts make the code way quicker then my loops. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @YowE3K, Pete's code made me think it updated _some_ cells of column B only because those were the ones to be strictly updated and so he preferred to "save" one column. That's why I went with a two columns array to fully exploit arrays "boost" and overwrite column B values